# How to change the value of a dropdown box from within it's own change function so that the change function is called again

Tags: javascript, jquery

I run some code when a value is selected from a drop-down box:

```
$('#temp_id').change( function() {
    if ($('#temp_id').val() == "temp_val") {
        $('#temp_id').val("temp_val2");    
    }
}):
```

This code runs ok, but the `$('#temp_id').val("temp_val");` line changes the value of the dropdown box without causing the change function to run again, which I need it to. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work methinks:

```
$('#temp_id').change( function() {
    if ($('#temp_id').val() == "temp_val") {
        $('#temp_id').val("temp_val2");    
        $('#temp_id').change(); // or $('#temp_id').trigger('change');
    }
}):
```

You just need to explicitly trigger the event again.